# Ruby on Rails, User Models and Active Admin query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, devise, activeadmin, models

I am using Active Admin in my application.

The application has a Users model (Devise) but I have 3 user groups - parents, teachers and students. Each has their own model.

e.g

```
student.rb

belongs_to :user

user.rb

has_one :student



parent.rb

belongs_to :user

user.rb

has_one :parent
```

What I am trying to do here is store the attributes that would be the same across the user groups in the Users model so "first_name, last_name, email" etc and then using the individual user models to store attributes that are unique to each user group. I am using a one to one relationship between the main users table and the three user group tables.

Here (note I have not displayed all attributes in the user group tables):

[image]

The problem is this is not working out so well with Active Admin. In the view I have to create a user and then assign a parent and a student in different views. I would like to have a single form where, for example, a student's user record can be put in with the attributes from the main Users table as well as their unique attributes in the students table without having to go to multiple model views to complete records. It's too convoluted.

Is there a way to render the inputs from different models in the one view? i.e in students have "first name", "last name"...from the Users table along with the inputs unique to a student?

If you were taking the approach I am taking here what method would you follow? I'm not even sure I am doing the associations right. In fact i'm not even sure this is the most efficient way to do this.

I am using enums to assign the roles.

Would appreciate any guidance here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Student`s, `Guardian`s, and `Teacher`s are all a type of User. Why not consolidate them into a single type and use inheritance to represent them as a common type?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # ...
end

class Teacher < User
  # ...
end

class Guardian < User
  # ...
end

class Student < User
  # ...
end
```

You'll need to add a `type` column via a migration, and also write a task to merge them into a common table, but it will likely be worth the effort.

See STI in Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html.

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to go the STI  route, you'll have to use nested attributes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guardian
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
end
```

Then add a custom `form` in `admin/user.rb` ():

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Inputs" do
      # ...
      f.input :email
      # ...
    end

    f.inputs "Guardian Attributes", for: [:guardian, f.object.guardian || Guardian.new] do |g|
      g.input :mobile_no
    end

    # Repeat for teacher, Student, etc...
  end
end
```

If you're using strong parameters, make sure you whitelist the appropriate params for User, guardian_attributes, etc.

In my opinion, the nesting here is pretty ugly and having this normalized schema is going to be difficult to maintain and query.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i tried STI before but several sources warned against using STI for this purpose? The outcome was somewhat better than now but I was scared off it a little bit. Is STI a safe and robust way to go?

Comment: The drawback is that there's some redundancy -- you'll have some fields in your table that only apply to certain user types (eg `class_id` on student). But I think that's a small price to pay. Is there overlap in the behaviors, views and controllers for each of these different types of users? If so, I'd seriously consider using a single table to represent these user models.

Comment: I updated my answer for the non-STI approach, you'll have to use `nested_params` in your forms.

Comment: Thanks very much. There is some overlap but not very much. I will give your alternative to STI a try. If it does not suit I don't mind having another go at STI. Very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I just tried the nested attributes approach and it is a lot closer to what I am looking for. Now if I could only get the nested fields to appear uniquely when signing up each user i'd be flying but that's another day's work!

Comment: Say if i'm signing up a student, it would be preferable if "guardian attributes" or "teacher attributes" was not there for example on that user form. I am using enums for the user roles. I don't know if anything can be done that says if I choose "student" as the role then the "student attributes" options would appear. I guess that would be complicated?

Comment: You can use something like `f.object.guardian.present?`, but only when editing an existing user because `f.object.guardian.present?` is always `false` for a new user. That's what's really funky about this approach -- your DB schema implies a user can "have" a `guardian`, `teacher` AND `student` which doesn't model or reflect the reality of your system. Really these types should be mutually exclusive and using an enum to enforce mutual exclusivity is a bit of a hack/abuse of the enum type. It's almost like you're re-implementing STI your own version of STI a very roundabout way.

Comment: Ok thanks. I need to do more research in to this. Curiously the nested forms don't update the corresponding tables. For example when I put information in the mobile no field under guardian attributes I don't get an error but the record is not saved in the guardians table? Whereas if I go to the guardians view and put a record in there it saves.

Comment: Yup, that's because you're not whitelisting the permitted params: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It automatically associates the user with the information put in the nested form too. That's great!